# How can I show only the commits made on a branch that has already been merged back into the parent?

Tags: git, logging, commit

The scenario is a branch was created off master, work was done and it has been merged back into master.  The normal commands I would use to review a branch now return nothing:

```
git log --no-merges master..
```

and

```
git diff `git merge-base master HEAD`..HEAD
```

Comment: FYI there's a shorthand for `git diff` for comparing the merge-base of `X` and `Y`, vs `Y`: `git diff X...Y`.  In this case that would be `git diff master...HEAD` for instance.  (It fails here because the merge-base of those two is just `HEAD`.)

Answer (score 0):

Where was the branch point?  If `A` is the hash of the point at which your branch split off from master, and B is the merge commit then you can do:

```
git diff A^..B
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll call the branch `branch` here, and for the sake of example, show commands used:

```
$ git checkout -b branch  # was on master
... work and commit ...   # for, say, four commits
$ git checkout master
... work and commit ...   # just to create commit "l" below on master
$ git merge branch
$ git branch -d branch
```

Assuming no new commits added to `master` since the merge, your graph now looks like this:

```
...-b-------l-m   <-- master
     \       /
      o-o-o-*     ["branch", before deleting the label]
```

What you're looking for is to compare commit `b`, the merge-base, with commit `*`, which was the tip of branch `branch`, back when it existed; or to log from commit `*` (inclusive) back to commit `b` (excluding `b` itself).

The trick here is to use git's [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) syntax.  Commit `m` on `master` is a merge commit and thus has at least two parents.  I will assume that the label `master` names commit `m`; if you've added more commits on `master`, you'll need to walk back along the chain of commits to find `m` first.

The "first" parent is `master^1` or simply `master^`.  The "second" parent of commit `m` is `master^2`, and this names commit `*`.

Finding `b` is potentially trickier.  However, the secret here (which you're already using when you write `git log master..`) is that *you* don't have to find it, you can let *git* find it for you.

The revision syntax `x..y` really means<sup>1</sup> `y ^x`:<sup>2</sup> find all commits starting from `y` and working backwards, but erase from that result, all commits starting from `x` and working backwards.  So if you write:

```
git log master^..master^2
```

this "means" `master^2 --not master^`, i.e., start from `master^2`—that's commit `*`—and work backwards "forever", but remove all commits found by starting at `master^`—that's commit `l`—and working backwards "forever".  Starting at `l` and working backwards, we remove commit `b` and all previous history, so this names exactly the commits that were only on `branch`.

(I created `l` so that `b` is not simply `master^`: the first parent of commit `m` on `master` is now `l` rather than `b`, so `master^` names commit `l`.  However, without `l` this would all still work.  In this case `master^` would name commit `b` directly and `master^..master^2` would still do what you wanted.)

For the `git diff` case, you really do have to find commit `b`, but you can use `git merge-base` to do it, or the special three-dot `git diff` syntax.

As an exercise, suppose there *are* some commits on `master` since the merge:

```
...-b-------l-m-n-o-p   <-- master
     \       /
      o-o-o-*
```

Now `master` refers to commit `p`, `master^` and `master~1` refer to `o`, `master^^` and `master~2` refer to `n`, and so forth.  Find some ways (in [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)) to name commit `m`.  What commit does `master~3^2` name?

---

<sup>1</sup>Except in `git diff`, which treats `..` and `...` specially.  Except for combined diff cases, git diff always compares two commits—or more precisely, two trees—so here `x..y` just means "commit `x` and commit `y`, with `x` on the left and `y` on the right", and `x...y` is gimmicked to mean "(merge-base of `x` and `y` on the left), (`y` on the right)".  (Left and right might also be called "from" and "to".)

<sup>2</sup>Note that the `^` in `^x` comes *before* x, while the `^` in `master^` comes *after* `master`.  The position of the `^` is crucial here: as a prefix, it means "not", but as a suffix it means "find a parent".